# Why is fwrite & fread printing garbage?

Tags: c

When The following code is run, why is there extra garbage printed alongside the HALLO string?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *binfile;

    binfile = fopen("binary.bin", "wb+");

    char arr[5] = "HALLO";
    int integer = 1;
    double doub = 1.2345;

    fwrite(arr, sizeof(arr), 1, binfile);
    fwrite(&integer, sizeof(int), 1, binfile);
    fwrite(&doub, sizeof(double), 1, binfile);

    fclose(binfile);

    binfile = fopen("binary.bin", "r");

    char arr2[5];
    int integer2;
    double doub2;

    fread(arr2, sizeof(arr2), 1, binfile);
    fread(&integer2, sizeof(int), 1, binfile);
    fread(&doub2, sizeof(double), 1, binfile);

    printf("%s\n", arr2);
    printf("%d\n", integer2);
    printf("%lf\n", doub2);

    fclose(binfile);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Open the file in binary `binfile = fopen("binary.bin", "rb");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Becuase you have not allowed for the null terminator on the string.

Ok, some more detail.  You have not made it clear what you're trying to do, so let's assume you want to write 5 char bytes.  The problem is that when you read back your 5 chars you read them back into a char array (fine) then try to print that array with no null terminator - not fine.

So either read them back into a new array and set

```
newarray[5]=0;
```

or print it out safe in the knowledge that you have 5 chars

```
printf("%5.5s",array);
```

(something like that anyway)

Comment: So basically you always have to have one more char than is in the string?

Comment: There are no strings here.  There is just a character array.  A string is a character array that has a null terminator.

Comment: Ok, you have not allowed for the null terminator on the character array.  Happy?

Comment: @EngineeringO_o You also need to set the byte following the "string" you `fread` to \0, or write and read the null terminator with the text. (This is one reason why binary formats are annoying to work with.)

Comment: You read data into `arr2` using `fread`. Text files rarely contain null characters, so `arr2` does not contain a *string* (defined as a sequence of characters terminated by, and including, a `'\0'` null character). You then write data from `arr2` using `printf("%s\n", arr2`);`. `printf`'s `"%s"` format requires an argument that points to a (null-terminated) string. You can use `fwrite` to write the data (like `printf`, it's equivalent to a series of `fputc` calls).

Comment: You *can* use modifiers on `printf`'s `"%s"` format to print unterminated character data, but I wouldn't do it; I'd just use `fwrite`. But since you're reading data from a *binary* file, you might want to reconsider dumping it to stdout at all.

Comment: "There are no strings here." -- "HALLO" is a string literal. The statement in the answer, "you have not allowed for the null terminator on the string" is correct, and the response is not merely pointlessly pedantic, it is factually incorrect, not only in terms of the C language, but in more geneneral semantic terms ... those 5 bytes represent a string, which is an abstract notion of a sequence of characters.

Comment: arr definition should be `char arr[6] = "HALLO";` to reserve 1 more byte for '\0'

Comment: Who voted for W. Purcell's comment that C doesn't have strings?
I have homework for you: Download the current C11 standard and search for the term "string". 

There are important differences when speaking about "char arrays" and "strings". 
Char arrays are just arrays of single byte characters ((d)words in case of wchar_t). A char array does not imply nor require the use of a zero terminator.

Talking about strings and their usage commonly implies zero-termination. Also, strings might consist of multi-byte characters (MBC).

Answer (score 1):

*printf("%s\n", arr2)* interprets *arr2* as a pointer to a string, not as a char array.
Since your char array does not end with a zero terminator, *printf* happily prints whatever is stored in the memory locations following the char array.

This code snippet should work:

```
char arr2[5+1];
fread(arr2, sizeof(arr2) - 1, 1, binfile);
arr2[sizeof(arr2) - 1] = '\0';
printf("%s\n", arr2);
```